# replace all text before and after a certain string using a regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

"Text before the string I want to get. Description: **This is the string I want to keep.** Rating: 5 stars."

From this string I want to cut of the first part and the last part. Only the middle is what I need. The program I use to load these strings can do a RegEx "Search and Replace". So I can replace the first and last part of the string with a space to empty these parts.

The words Description and Rating are always present in this form, so can be used to create the  RegEx.

Comment: Which ones have you tried? Otherwise we won't be able to help you with learning…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing matches of the following regex with an empty string (or a space):

```
^.*?Description:|Rating:.*$
```

This may have some unexpected behavior if "Text before the string I want" can also contain "Description:" or the string you want to keep can contain "Rating:".

Note that technically the anchors (`^` and `$`) are not necessary here, but they are still useful to make it clear that everything from the beginning of the string up to "Description:" is being removed, as well as everything from "Rating:" until the end of the string.

Comment: Works as expected, although I had to add a ^ as closing character.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your tool/programming supports look-around:

```
'(?<=Description: ).*(?=Rating: )'
```

will give you the middle part. so that you don't have to "replace". just extract the matched part.

Comment: This is a nice alternative, although it is not supported by the tool I am using.